# How can I search in my array containing many objects, then updating it so no duplicates are shown

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, sorting

Looking for assistance on how to update my array DATA[] and display my values correctly in a table.

The data is showing correctly but there are duplicate pairs. Is it possible to find and replace the details per pair? If the pair does not exist in the array, add it. When the app is run, initial response is all pairs and details. After that, updates occur, so i need to update the details without pushing it to the array.

```js
function App() {

  const DATA = []
  const [TickerFeed, SetTickerFeed] = useState([]);

    orionUnit.priceFeed.ws.subscribe("allTickers", {
      callback: (tickers) => {

        let keys = zodUtil.util.objectKeys(tickers);
        let values: DATA[] = zodUtil.util.objectValues(tickers);

        //keys is Pair
        //values contains data about the pair
        
        //for every key, push to the DATA array.
        //need to find the pair in DATA[] and set the details from values.pairName

        for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
        {
          DATA.push({
            Pair: keys[i],
            LastPrice: values[i].lastPrice, 
            Volume: values[i].volume, 
            OpenPrice: values[i].openPrice, 
            LowPrice: values[i].lowPrice, 
            HighPrice: values[i].highPrice })
        }
        SetTickerFeed(DATA);
      }

    } 
     
  );

  return (
  
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <DataTable>
        <DataTable.Header>
          <DataTable.Title>Pair</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title>LastPrice</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title>Volume</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title>OpenPrice</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title>LowPrice</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title>HighPrice</DataTable.Title>
        </DataTable.Header>
         
         
         //Currently works but contains duplicates. Once an update from the callback has been received, its just pushed to the array and not updated!!
        {TickerFeed.map((item, index) => (
          <DataTable.Row key={item.Pair}>
            <DataTable.Cell>{item.Pair}</DataTable.Cell>
            <DataTable.Cell numeric>{item.LastPrice}</DataTable.Cell>
            <DataTable.Cell numeric>{item.Volume}</DataTable.Cell>
            <DataTable.Cell numeric>{item.OpenPrice}</DataTable.Cell>
            <DataTable.Cell numeric>{item.LowPrice}</DataTable.Cell>
            <DataTable.Cell numeric>{item.HighPrice}</DataTable.Cell>
          </DataTable.Row>
        ))}

        
        </DataTable>
       
    </View>
  );
}
```

**The objects displayed from keys and values object inside the callback, console.log(keys,values):**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your data object looks like. So, I assume this way to simulate the existing thing in `DATA`.

- If existing, update the existing data.
- If none, add the object to `DATA`.

```js
let DATA = [
  {
    Pair: "FTM-ETH",  // Change this to "BAL-USDT" for simulating the existing object in DATA.
    LastPrice: 0,
    Volume: 0,
    OpenPrice: 0,
    LowPrice: 0,
    HighPrice: 0,
  },
];
let keys = [
  "AVA-USDT",
  "BNB-ORN",
  "BAL-USDT"
];
let values = [
  {
    lastPrice: 1,
    volume: 2,
    openPrice: 3,
    lowPrice: 4,
    highPrice: 5,
  },
  {
    lastPrice: 10,
    volume: 11,
    openPrice: 12,
    lowPrice: 13,
    highPrice: 14,
  },
  {
    lastPrice: 20,
    volume: 21,
    openPrice: 22,
    lowPrice: 23,
    highPrice: 24,
  },
];

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  let existingPairInData = DATA.find((pair) => pair.Pair === keys[i]);
  console.log('Existing Pair in DATA :>> ', existingPairInData);

  if (existingPairInData) {
    // Update exist data in array with new data
    existingPairInData.LastPrice = values[i].lastPrice;
    existingPairInData.Volume = values[i].volume;
    existingPairInData.OpenPrice = values[i].openPrice;
    existingPairInData.LowPrice = values[i].lowPrice;
    existingPairInData.HighPrice = values[i].highPrice;
  } else {
    DATA.push({
      Pair: keys[i],
      LastPrice: values[i].lastPrice,
      Volume: values[i].volume,
      OpenPrice: values[i].openPrice,
      LowPrice: values[i].lowPrice,
      HighPrice: values[i].highPrice,
    });
  }
}

console.log('Updated exist object :>> ', DATA);
```

Comment: Thanks man will give it a try! Just added the object now on this post as an example of what it looks like.

Comment: Another thing, "keys" are the pairNames I get from the object, not a number. You think this is unique enough?

Comment: I updated the code snippet to match your example data.

Could you explain more about what is unique enough?

Comment: The 'keys' or pairName is unique enough, no further need for explanation. Just needed the logic on how to update my array or push new data into it. Thank you for the help appreciate it!